# how to decode ldap3 thumbnailPhoto to display it in template?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ldap3

I'm trying to load a picture from active directory into a django template.

This is the result :

```
"b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x02\x01\x01\x01\x01\..."
```

I have seen the PHP method and tried to implement it using python with no success. I also tried the `base64.decode`, to save it in an image file and convert it using pil then load it, `base64.decodebase64`, I even tried to convert it using javascript and load it in src but all these methods didn't work, I have read a lot of articles but none helped me.

ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try to put the base64 string into the src of `img` tag? something like `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,base64_string" />`

Comment: yes, i did it didn't work.

Comment: Please show the code you are using so that we can help

Comment: thanks Amine and Nalin, i've found a way to do it with an api.

Comment: if you found the solution then u should add an answer so that other person can resolve for the same issue.

Comment: what was the solution that you have found as i am running on the same issue right now.

Answer (score 2):

I know that it's old. But if someone struggles with the same problem here's how I did it:

```
import base64
...
thumbnailPhoto = base64.b64encode(entry.thumbnailPhoto.value).decode("utf-8")
```

And then in the html template

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,{{ thumbnailPhoto }}">
```

Comment: Forgot to menthion that my code is for Django project, but it's only relevant to passing the variable to html.